# Magento promotions rule gets deactivated

Tags: magento, promotions

I am using magento on www.gotech.ro, and they have different promotions from time to time. That is why i am using the promotions tab in the admin area, to create price rules (in this case -15%). The problem is that after a while (one day or more), the rule just gets deactivated, even if in admin there is no expiration date set, or it is set sometime in the future. Also, the rule says activated, but on the site, there are the full prices, with no rule applied to them.

I've searched a lot of forums to see a similar problem, but i couldn't find anything. I am using Magento 1.5.1.

Regards,
Vali.

Comment: Assuming that the promotions worked when you first set them up, Make sure that "Uses per coupon" and "Uses per customer" are set to 0.

Comment: I am using "Catalog Price Rules", so the promotion is made to every product that i have selected through the rules i have set in the conditions tab. The "Uses per coupon" and "Uses per customer" are for the "Shopping cart price rules".

Answer (score 1):

Is the Magento Cron job running every night? In Magento, promotions need to be re-applied every day. This is done automatically by the Cron job. If it is not running, you would see exactly the behavior your describe.